# Internal Working of Fabric Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to know how Fabric Composer works internally by transforming .bna file to chaincode and how key-value pairs are actually stored in the couch db/state db for the given assets, participants and transactions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see the links here.

Composer Architecture: https://www.slideshare.net/SimonStone8/hyperledger-composer-architecture

This architecture deep dive shows the internal workings, in terms of runtime architecture -> https://www.slideshare.net/dselman/hyperleger-composer-architecure-deep-dive

This article will also be useful to see a side-by-side comparison:
https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/#more-901

On key/value - see here -> [What is the relationship between assets created in a composer network to the assets in fabric chaincode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452723/what-is-the-relationship-between-assets-created-in-a-composer-network-to-the-ass)

Finally, do note its now called Hyperledger Composer and no longer called Fabric Composer, just FYI.