# How objects are being transferred in invoking Hyperledger Composer smart contracts?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a POC with Hyperledger composer. As part of my model I have an asset called contract. It is defined as follows:

```
asset Contract identified by contractId {
  o String contractId
  --> Customer customer
  --> Supplier supplier
  --> Commodity commodity
  o Double minDaily
  o Double maxDaily
  o Double maxAnnual
}
```

In my chaincode I need to make a number of variables from this contract asset to check a number of conditions. It is as follows:

```
async function nominate(tx) {

    let customer = tx.contract.customer;
    let supplier = tx.contract.supplier; 
    let minDaily = tx.contract.minDaily;
    let maxDaily = tx.contract.maxDaily;
    let maxAnnual = tx.contract.maxAnnual;
    let quantity = tx.quantity;
    // the rest of the code...
}
```

My question is when invoking a transaction, does the contract asset (or any other asset generally speaking), go through the transaction itself, or just a reference to the asset is in the transaction. As I said this is general. For all assets like customer, does it go through the transaction, or a reference to it is there? This is also my concern in Hyperledger Fabric as well. Composer is just a tool. I would like to know what the mechanism in Fabric is as well.

I am concerned with security reasons. If Contract asset goes through the transaction, I am worried if at any layer of application a hacker can change parameters of the contract, while all those parameters must be immutable and are only there to be checked against conditions.

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: NO, just the transaction object generally. A reference (to the asset is passed (not the object itself) so it can retrieve the asset's world state by id on the ledger  - and that's because your runtims smart contract has been coded to interrogate that asset in your transaction logic etc from the world state. Effectively (during the execution of the SC)  points at an related asset instance in URI representation (and obviously all the methods that go with that, eg checking type or existence etc etc).  contd...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452723/what-is-the-relationship-between-assets-created-in-a-composer-network-to-the-ass  . Your inputs to the business network would be secured (between submitter and runtime busness network) anyway and that business network is deployed to multiple peers, in different orgs on a blockchain network

Comment: So @PaulO'Mahony you mean only a reference to Contract asset is sent on the network, and it is not being serialized, right?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony you also mentioned that inputs to the business network is secured. Is it because of using TLS to encrypt the data before sending it?

Comment: 1) right 2)  yes, data in transit = TLS . Even if you weren't using a blockchain to send trxn data/inputs,  ie primarily to provide secure comms, privacy and data integrity.